# Where can I go to learn and understand cloth physics?

Tags: java, physics

I found [this](http://bluethen.com/wordpress/index.php/processing-apps/curtain/) (you need Java to play with it) and since have been fascinated by cloth physics. I don't understand the logic behind the code at all though...is there any essential reading or resources for beginners?

Comment: It is a great link, I'm still playing with that curtain! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloth physics is actually only spring physics, where each "point" of the cloth is connected to its immediate neighbors (usually in a square grid) by a spring.

Pulling on a point then stresses the springs surrounding that point, which stretch temporarily.  As they retract, they accelerate the neighboring points, which then "pull" on their surrounding springs.

[Here's another demo](http://www.jrc313.com/processing/cloth/index.html) (demonstrating their spring library).
Look to [this paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20070709214337/http://www.emeyex.com/site/tuts/Springs.pdf) for some details.

Comment: So I should try to get a library with spring physics so I can play around with it?

Comment: That's one way to do it, but not the only way.

Comment: @Miles, yes; however, it isn't very hard to implement spring physics directly from physics textbook formula.  I'm also going to edit in a link to a PDF you might find interesting.

Comment: @Duffy, in the Physics world, there has always been an understanding that it is a model, and depending on the fidelity needed, the model may be simplified or broken down into its constituent parts.  To simulate cloth on a computer screen for the most common cases, one need only consider a connected spring mesh of semi-rigid springs.  Much like considering trajectory of a projectile in most simulations only need consider Newtonian mechanics.  True fidelity could be approached by considering shear, tension, and friction in a mesh of intertwined cylinders; however, that's not what he linked to.

Comment: He said he was "fascinated", if you read the original question.  He never said what he wanted to do with it.  I think it's important to make it clear that models have different levels of fidelity.  I can't tell what the right answer is without more context, but neither can you.  Your guess is no better or worse than mine.

Comment: The link to the paper now leads to a non-PG site.

Comment: @illuminator3 Thanks, it's fixed now, referencing the PDF from the Wayback machine.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how faithfully you want or need to represent the physics.  All models represent a choice of features to include and omit.

Doing it properly means knowing a lot of physics fundamentals: continuum mechanics for large displacements and strains and a good material model for fabric.  I'd recommend [Malvern](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134876032) or [Fung](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133299120) for the former and a literature search for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

[paper on mass spring system](https://www.math.hmc.edu/~depillis/MATH164/MATH164_StudentProjects_2003/COCONNOR/ClothSimulation/final_report.pdf)

Theres something called a mass spring system, I suggest you google it and work it out. It's basically based on beams and points. You have rectangles with points which are the corners and beams which are the lines connecting them. The points can be moved and the beams stretch but the beams can only stretch a certain amount, if they stretch too much they will break allowing the points to disconnect.